# how can i arrange widgets in different screens android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I want to make a layout fill with buttons in this way:

[image]

I tried with a table layout, but i can not get the right space between the buttons, also when i tried in different screens sizes, everything screw up (even when i used android:layout_weight) so now i am tring with a relative layout, but i can not get the buttons to take the right size when the screen changes, i already read hints about dealing with different screens sizes, so i am using dp and wrap_content, but nothing works, here is my code:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="31dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="150dp"
        
        android:background="@layout/press"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/reading"
        android:text="@string/option" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="28dp"
        
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="150dp"
        
        android:background="@layout/press"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/reading"
        android:text="@string/option" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I am tring to set the first row of buttons, but the Button2 dont resize as it should be, what am i doing wrong? or how can i accomplish this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<LinearLayout
android:orientation = "vertical">


<LinearLayout
android:orientation = "horizontal"/>

2 Buttons here.
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Dont forget to include the linear layout's height and width. Hope this helps.

Comment: actually inside my main linearlayout y have the code i posted

Comment: Are you getting errors? Try replacing RelativeLayout to LinearLayout. Or you can also try making a LinearLayout below your RelativeLayout.

Comment: i am not getting errors, the problem is the Button2 does not resize as it should be in another screen sizes

Comment: You're using a drawable, don't you? Maybe your images or text inside your button are not in the same size. It will really affect the size of your button because you used wrap_content as your layoutwidth and layoutheight.

Comment: Basically, fill_parent will give you the same and exact measurement of your parent, while the wrap_content will only display the width or height of your widget. So it will depend on the needs of your layout.